# Magento 2: Collection getSelect does not load the results

Tags: magento2, php

I have this method

```
  public function getCarBrands() {
    return $this->_objectManager->create('Scandimedia\Wheels\Model\CarModels')->getCollection()->getSelect()->group('brand');
}
```

But when I execute it and try to foreach the results with:

```
foreach($this->getCarBrands() as $model) {
echo $model->getData();
```

}

It does not do anything.
But when I echo it returns:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `scandimedia_wheels_car_models` AS `main_table` GROUP BY `brand`
```

If I do get_class, it gives me this result: Magento\Framework\DB\Select

How can I actually load the results from the group and get the data without running the string as a query?

Comment: Have you check with `$this->getCarBrands()->getSize();`?

Comment: Do you  inject the model collection factory into your constructor?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to add `addFieldToSelect('*')` to your collection.**

### You need to modify:

```
public function getCarBrands() {

    $collection =  $this->_objectManager->create('Scandimedia\Wheels\Model\CarModels')->getCollection();
    $collection->addFieldToSelect('*')
    $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.brand');
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it didn't work.

foreach($this->getCarBrands() as $brand) {
    echo $brand->getData();
}

still returns nothing and get_class of the response still returns Magento\Framework\DB\Select.

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**Working example with CustomerFactory

**add in class properties**
protected $_customerFactory;

**inject in constructor**
\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory

**Initialize**
$this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;

$whereDobExpression = "Any custom expression"
"e" can be used as alias for the main table
**example:**

$whereDobExpression = "e.is_active = 1"

**!IMPORTANT**
you need to add 
$customerCollection->**addFieldToSelect**('*');
it will not work without it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure, **getSelect()** will never return data. It is just Select Object, and there is no return data.

So, usually I use **getSelect()** as like query builder, to return a raw query use **__toString()** after **getSelect()** method, and than run the raw query.

Answer (score 0):

You should use load() method

```
 $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(
            new \Zend_Db_Expr("status ,COUNT(*) AS `num` ")
        );
 $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.status');
 $orderData = $collection->load();
```